# I have a plist that is an array of dictionaries I need to save to documents directory is this code correct?

Tags: cocoa, directory, documents

Is the code below correct for saving to disk?

```
   // get the path to the "Documents" directory
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

// get the path to our plist ("Documents/foo.plist")
NSString *plistPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"foo.plist"];

// read or create plist

NSMutableDictionary *dict;
// check if our plist already exists in the Documents directory...
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
if ( [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:plistPath] ) {
// ...if it does, read it
NSLog(@"dict existed, reading %@", plistPath);
dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
} else {
// ...if it doesn't, create it
NSLog(@"dict didn't exist, creating...");
dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:1];
```

Comment: Why not try if it works?

Comment: Agree with Eiko - If you're having specific problems, disclose them, otherwise, the answer is "run it yourself to find out and stop wasting others' time."

Comment: There is not much info for us to go on. Are there any errors? If yes, what are they. I hope you are not thinking we will copy/paste this in a new Xcode project and see if it works? You can do that yourself.

Comment: To Eiko and Joshua Nozzi. I apologize for posting improperly. I'd been chasing down this question (how to save data persistently)for several days and in a moment of frustration (understatement) just posted the above hoping for an answer. I've discovered archiving and will take that route.

Comment: Andy Elliott: This code won't read in an archive. (Well, it will, but the contents won't be what you expect.) They're in different formats. If you want to read a plist, as shown in this question, you must write a plist. If you want to decode an archive, you must encode an archive.

Comment: Yep, I get that. I'm taking a different approach.

Answer (score 2):

No.

For one thing, it's missing a closing brace at the end, but maybe you just left that out when copying the code into the question.

For another, the code *reads in a dictionary*; it does not get an array (of anything) from anywhere, nor does it write anything (array or anything else) out.

It sounds like you copied the code from somewhere, hoping that it's what you need. Don't do that. **Write your own code.** Read code if you want, but only *read* it; do not just copy code into your program without understanding what it does, and don't rely on other people to tell you what code does.

In order to be a programmer in any language or framework, you **must** be able to read code in that language/framework. Read the [Objective-C Programming Language](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/) and read the [Cocoa Fundamentals Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/); once you know the concepts those guides teach, all that remains is to practice reading code.

You must also, obviously, be able to write code in the target language/framework. Copying other people's code is not a substitute. At best, you will end up with a shoddy program that is flaky or just doesn't work; at worst (if you're “programming” as a contractor or employee), you will be guilty of plagiarism.

Comment: Thanks Peter. I'm certainly not a contractor. I'm a Nashville songwriter just learning something new! Saving data was not something the books I've been reading addressed and I can see why. It's a challenging concept. I have a handle on it now.